# is there anyway to have a shortcut key to switch to a different folder in outlook

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2007

i constantly have to use the mouse to switch between different folders in my inbox.  is there a shortcut key to do this or a macro that allows you to switch to different folders

I have the following folders:

Inbox
-- CCedMail
-- Distribution Lists

and i want to be able to toggle between the three of these without using the mouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure you could use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) for this.

Answer (score -1):

Ctrl + 1 gets you to Inbox

Once you're there, Shift + Down Arrow moves you to the first subfolder (CCedMail)

Down Arrow again to other subfolders

When you're on the subfolder you like, hit Enter to see the contents.

Comment: Actually, once you're at Inbox, you can just hit the down arrow, you don't need to hold Shift

Comment: it seems that when you use these shortcuts teh focus goes on the emails (not the folders) so it just moves up the emails in the folder

Comment: True. You can't use ctrl + 1 to get to inbox. It looks like you have to click on the Inbox folder or click the "Mail" button in the navigation pane. Once you're there you can use the down arrow to navigate to a folder. When you find the folder you want, press "Enter" to display its mail. Then press tab to go from folder focus to mail item focus. Tab again goes back to folder focus.